# How to open NTFS partition on Ubuntu without Windows' hidden files?

Tags: partitioning, windows, ntfs

My computer is dual boot with Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8, but when I open NTFS partition in Ubuntu, crap files like: **System Volume Information** $RECYCLE.BIN appear. How can I get rid of these files?

Comment: What is crap to one person is essential for Windows to function for another person ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `$RECYCLE.BIN` is for Recyclebin allocation form your hard disk partition.I mean how much HDD partition was allocated for specific partition.
  `System Volume Information` bears the useful info regarding your volume

So If I were you I will keep those files. Even you remove,  they will come again.

Answer (score 0):

Those files are windows system files. They're hidden in windows by default. That's why you don't see them in windows but they do exist. And if you do remove them and open windows again they'd be recreated.